# Birt Report Viewer with maven not starting

Tags: maven, tomcat, runtime, reportviewer, birt

I'm trying to get the Birt View Report running through Maven, but I'm encountering problems for some days now and I can't seem to find a solution. I use the following Depedency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
      <artifactId>viewservlets</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
      <artifactId>engineapi</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run this I get a blank page with my executable tomcat package and when I place it in my 'manual' tomcat I this:

> org.apache.catalina.core.standardcontext.startinternal error
>   listenerstart

Am I forgetting something? When I copy the lib folder from the WebViewerExample in the project en not use these depedencies it works, but that's not the way ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <birt.runtime.version>4.3.0</birt.runtime.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.runtime.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.apache.poi</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
```